# Python woes with ssids, utf-8, and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, wifi

I'm trying to read the list of available wifi connections from python.  I use the following code to do so:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(('sudo', 'iwlist', 'wlan0', 'scan'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', 'ESSID'), stdin=ps.stdout)
ssids = filter(None, sorted(dict.fromkeys(re.findall('"([^"]*)"', output))))
```

This produces a list of available ssids.  Great.  But if I have an ssid with an apostrope in it, I get something like:

> Ryan\xe2\x80\x99s iPhone

Cool..the only way I can get this to display correctly on my web app is if I run `str.decode('string_escape')` on each of the ssids. It then looks like:

> Ryan’s iPhone

But then...when I try to write that value to `wpa_supplicant.conf`, I get:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in
>   position...

Ok...so I try to utf-8 encode it before it is submitted, and I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x32 in
>   position...

I've tried utf-8 encoding the ssids initially (instead of using `decode('string_escape')`, but the character still just shows up and is passed as `\xe2\x80\x99`.  I don't know what I can do to simply display and pass this like any other normal character.

Comment: "my web app" : can you give more details?

Comment: just a flask app on nginx where I display a list of wifi ssids to the user, they select one and enter the password for it, then submit the form.   The form records those credentials to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and attempts to connect the device the app is hosted on to that wifi.

Comment: I think \xe2 etc are physical string non encoded. So you should use such string for communication (and the unescaped for displaying to humans)